# 'Unable to lookup JNDI name' in Hibernate 4.3.6 with Tomcat 8

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I am using Spring 4.1.1 and am trying to setup Hibernate. This is my `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
public class PersistencyBeansConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configuration = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration();
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class).setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect").setProperty("hibernate.connection.datasource", "jdbcConnector").setProperty("hibernate.order_updates", "true");
            System.out.println("Hibernate Configuration loaded");
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            System.out.println("Hibernate serviceRegistry created");
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            return sessionFactory;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a data source declared in `context.xml` file of Tomcat 8:

```
<Resource
    name="jdbcConnector" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000" username="root"
    password="password" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_tutorial_db?characterEncoding=utf8"
/>
```

When I'm trying to run the application I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [jdbcConnector]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.demian.spring.tutorial.mvc.dao.PersistencyBeansConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(PersistencyBeansConfiguration.java:19)
    at org.demian.spring.tutorial.mvc.dao.PersistencyBeansConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d69d32e.CGLIB$buildSessionFactory$0(<generated>)
    at org.demian.spring.tutorial.mvc.dao.PersistencyBeansConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d69d32e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f8dc0fa4.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at org.demian.spring.tutorial.mvc.dao.PersistencyBeansConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d69d32e.buildSessionFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4751)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5175)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbcConnector] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbcConnector].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:818)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:152)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:134)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:114)
    ... 59 more
```

The strange thing about this error is that Spring doesn't have problems with the JNDI lookup I have inserted in one of my xml beans definition file:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbcConnector" id="dataSource"
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

If you need further details just ask in the comments. I am new to Hibernate and I apologise if my code is wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Use the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` instead of trying to manually configure hibernate and just inject the datasource. Do the lookup using a `JndiDataSourceLookup`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but this was resolved by upgrading hibernate-core to 4.3.6.Final.

See: [Closed bug report](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8818)

Comment: Going from "Hibernate 4.3.5.Final" to "4.3.6.Final" fixed my "NameNotFoundException" problem with Tomcat 8. Thx.